# React Native Change Navigation Bar Font

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ios9, navigationbar

I have read a bunch of posts and understand that so far there is no feature in React Native to change the font of a navigation bar, so I know I need to manually do it somehow. I have tried to paste the following code in AppDelegate.m in the React Native project I have

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
          @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bodoni 72" size:22.0],
          NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}];
```

but this doesn't work. I also thought I could try editing in RCTConvert.m manually. But that didn't work out either. Does anyone know what else I should try? 
Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If so, how?

Comment: What component is being used to render your navigation bar? Are you using the built-in Navigator/NavigatorIOS component, or are you using something different?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm assuming you are using NavigatorIOS. If not, the following doesn't apply.

Unfortunately your approach doesn't work due to the way React Native codes the Navigation Bar appearance changes. I made a tiny patch that would allow your code to work. I may submit this to React Native, but haven't decided yet:

```
--- a/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTWrapperViewController.m
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTWrapperViewController.m
@@ -115,9 +115,11 @@ static UIView *RCTFindNavBarShadowViewInView(UIView *view)
     bar.barTintColor = _navItem.barTintColor;
     bar.tintColor = _navItem.tintColor;
     bar.translucent = _navItem.translucent;
-    bar.titleTextAttributes = _navItem.titleTextColor ? @{
-      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: _navItem.titleTextColor
-    } : nil;
+    if (_navItem.titleTextColor != nil) {
+        NSMutableDictionary *newAttributes = bar.titleTextAttributes ? bar.titleTextAttributes.mutableCopy :  [NSMutableDictionary new];
+        [newAttributes setObject:_navItem.titleTextColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
+        bar.titleTextAttributes = newAttributes;
+    }

     RCTFindNavBarShadowViewInView(bar).hidden = _navItem.shadowHidden;
```